# Checking folders with VBS associators

Tags: vbscript, wmi, wmi-query, wql

I need to find out is the path to the folder includes hidden folders or not.
Does anybody know how to do it? I have to use associators. Now my script only shows is the exact folder hidden or not and not checking the path to it.

```
Dim xdoc

Function CreateFolders(objFile)
    Dim elem
    Dim attr
    Set elem = xdoc.CreateElement("Folder")
    Set attr = xdoc.CreateAttribute("Description")
    attr.Value = objFile.Description
    elem.SetAttributeNode attr
    Set CreateFolders = elem
End Function

Dim FilePath
Dim objFile
Dim root
Dim elem, elem1
Dim FilePath2

Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

If WScript.Arguments.Count > 0 Then
    sFile = WScript.Arguments(0)

    If oFSO.FileExists(sFile) Then
        Set oFile = oFSO.GetFile(sFile)
        sModify = oFile.DateLastModified
    End If
End If
FilePath2 = WScript.Arguments(0)

Set xdoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.6.0")
xdoc.AppendChild xdoc.CreateProcessingInstruction("xml", "version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""")
FilePath = "C:\Users\User\Downloads\My123.xml"

Set root = xdoc.CreateElement("Folders")
xdoc.AppendChild root

strComputer = "."

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
    & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set colFiles = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
    ("SELECT * FROM Win32_Directory WHERE Name = '" & FilePath2 & "'")

For Each objFile In colFiles
    Wscript.Echo objFile.Name & "  " & "Status: "  & objFile.Hidden
    Set elem = CreateFolders(objFile)
    root.AppendChild elem
Next

xdoc.Save FilePath
```

Comment: Take a look at the description of the tag `vbscript` and reconsider using it.

Comment: *I have to use associators.* Why? If this is a homework question: please show the actual task and what you already tried (there is no attempt to use associators in the code you posted).

Comment: Yes. It's a homework.
I don't know why should I use associators here and I was  just told to do that.